# cannot scroll normally after page scroll animation

Tags: jquery

I made the page scroll to div when the page itself is scrolled over 300px from the top. the problem is, after that animation scroll, I can't scroll back up normally.

```
$(function () {
    $(window).scroll(function () {
        console.log($(window).scrollTop());
        if ($(window).scrollTop() > 300) {
            //$( "body" ).animate({scrollTop:$wh });
            $('body').animate({
                scrollTop: $("#div2").offset().top
            }, 200);
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to upgrade your `if` condition

```
$(function () {
    var lastScroll = $(window).scrollTop();
    $(window).scroll(function () {
        var scrollTop = $(window).scrollTop();
        var divTop = $("#div2").offset().top;
            if ( scrollTop > lastScroll && scrollTop <= 300 ) {
            $('body').stop().animate({
                scrollTop: divTop
            }, 100);
        }
        lastScroll = scrollTop;
    });
});
```

only animate when current scrolltop bigger then the lastscroll (scrolling down)
and the client is after the 300px line.

```
        if ( scrollTop > lastScroll && scrollTop <= 300 ) {
```

working example

http://jsfiddle.net/JAy7Y/1/

Answer (score 1):

probably because the event gets fired all over again everytime you scroll :)

```
$(function () {
    $(window).bind('scroll.once', function () {
        console.log($(window).scrollTop());
        if ($(window).scrollTop() > 300) {
            //$( "body" ).animate({scrollTop:$wh });
            $('body').stop().animate({
                scrollTop: $("#div2").offset().top
            }, 200);
            $(window).unbind('scroll.once');
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: This is great, but it doesn't work AGAIN if I scroll all the way up and start scrolling down.